# How do you do Impersonation in UWP?

Tags: uwp, impersonation

I am working on UWP application. A scenario came where i want to change the current context user(current login user).For that i am trying to implement Impersonation in UWP. In general windows or web application I am able to change the current context user by using sample code available on following link:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User
But i am unable to implement this in UWP.
I want to implement impersonation in UWP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impersonation is not available for UWP applications. They are all tied to the current session user with only a restricted set of authorizations.

The [LogonUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx) API used to impersonate is only available to desktop/win32 apps.

You can check the list of all the supported Win32 API in UWP [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt592904.aspx).