# UWP User Impersonation

Tags: c#, networking, uwp, impersonation, hololens

I am trying to access a Network Share Folder on a Hololens Application. Within Unity I have a class which goes to a Network Share Folder grabs a model and loads it at run time. When I run it on the Hololens it seems it cannot find that network share and I suspect I need to impersonate a windows user and then access the network share that way. Has anyone ever done impersonation within a UWP application? I was thinking of creating a Class Library then importing the DLL but everything Ive tried from within the UWP class library doesn't work as all the examples are for .NET.

Regards,
Jay

Comment: Already answered, refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803421/how-do-you-do-impersonation-in-uwp?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you do Impersonation in UWP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803421/how-do-you-do-impersonation-in-uwp)

Comment: Yeah sorry I did search but did not see that. If I cannot perform an impersonation then do you know how I can access a network share from within a UWP (Hololens) Application?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't actually need to impersonate another user, but instead just authenticate to the other device as the current user, you should be able to do this with the `privateNetworkClientServer` and `enterpriseAuthentication` capabilities. You can also use the `FileOpenPicker` to let the user pick something from the network.

Comment: Yeah that's the problem I don't want the user to have to select the file using the FileOpenPicker I want to define which file to load in from the Network Share and then bring that into the Hololens Application. My current application created in Unity works fine. Its just when I deploy it to the Hololens it cannot find the file path

Comment: Did the capabilities help?

Comment: No the Hololens cannot see the folder still. This is the path its using "\\DESKTOP-NNME09I\Models\blueSquare.obj" enterpriseAuthentication ticked and privateNetworkClientServer ticked in the player settings in Unity and still no luck. All works fine in Unity. The folder properties in sharing has "Everyone" added so I am really stuck as to why I cant access that folder.